# Jplayer start from random song

Tags: php, jquery, jplayer

I have a playlist of 200 songs and what I need is, evertime the page loads, the player sta rts playing from a random song and continues from that song, rather than start playing from first song.

Is it doable and if yes how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the jPlayerPlaylist plugin that has a built-in shuffle option. http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

Comment: I think  the built-in shuffle always shuffles the entire playlist, I need to shuffle only the first song, when the player starts first time the song needs to be shuffled and then it continues from the next song without shuffling. @Laurens Swart

Comment: Could you show me your current Jplayer javascript and playlist.xml? I think I may have a solution.